# How to extract labels.txt file from tflite file?

Tags: android, tensorflow, kotlin, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to extract labels.txt file from **coco_ssd_mobilenet_v1_1.0_quant.tflite** but I don't know how to do it

output file should look like below :

apple
boy
bat
phone

like this but I can't be able to do it for using it in Kotlin android app development.
I am a beginner so sorry for my mistake.

Link of the Tensor flow [file](https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/lite-model/ssd_mobilenet_v1/1/metadata/1?lite-format=tflite)

Link of the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/examples/object_detection/overview)

Comment: What library are you using to interpret the tflite mode  ? Also clarify in detail what do you actually want in detail

Comment: I downloaded the model from Tensorflow website for object detection. I am a beginner so I don't know which library.
I have added a download link and site link

Comment: From where did you download the model from ?

Comment: @KaruneshPalekar I downloaded it from Tensorflow site check the updated question.

Comment: for tensorflow models: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/convert/metadata#read_the_associated_files_from_models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy way to  extract label file from a model(You can make use of debugger or model inspector's for the same) . The tensorflow lite file you have referred along with the labels can be found at Tensorflow's github . The path for the label is :

> https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android/app/src/main/assets/labelmap.txt

This are the labels for the which the model is trained for .

Comment: How did you get those labels.txt file

Comment: Those are from the official github

Comment: Isn't there is any other way to access the list in android app

Comment: Will check and revert on the same

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to get the `classes or labels` on which my `tflite` model was trained.

I got the classes by opening the `tflite` model using the `textEditor`.

By opening the `tflite` model in `textEditor` I got the `metadata` as well as the `classes` on which my model was trained.

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to read the associated files, such as the labels.txt, you can simply unzip the tflite file
https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/convert/metadata#read_the_associated_files_from_models

Comment: Please be more specific in your answer. Just copying a Link is not enough.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).